# How do I add numbers into a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I cannot find a way to put numbers in for loops. Can you help me?
I use Python 3.12.

I have tried putting an integer directly:

```
for x in 3 ** 2000
    print (x)
```

But it gave me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call back):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I tried using int, but it gave me the same error!
Can you help me?

Comment: seems you want to use [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range): `for x in range(3**2000):`

Comment: `3 ** 2000` is a very large integer. But it doesn't make sense to iterate an integer of any size. You could do `for x in range(3 ** 2000)` but that could take a significant amount of time to complete.

Comment: It will never complete.  That's a number with 950 digits.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think OP is trying to print the numbers 3 to 2000.

Comment: if the last comment is right, then adjust the operator and operands of the range function `for i in range(3, 2001):`

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? The answers/comments are all based on guesswork

Answer (score 1):

all for loops in python iterate over an iterable object in the backend (something like a for each in other languages), so you can't make a for loop directly through a number. You need to use the [range](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) function make an iterable object that the for loop can iterate through. In your case (assuming that you wanted to print the numbers from 3 to 2000):

```
for num in range(3, 2000):
    print(num)
```

would solve your problem.

If you are interested in what this is actually doing in the backend:
The range function is making a generator (just think of it as a sequence of items) based on the parameters you provided. For example `range(5)` returns the sequence `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`. The loop is then setting the iteration variable (num in the example above) to equal the elements in the sequence one at a time from first to last. Therefore, you can do the same thing with an array like this:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for num in arr:
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

you want use range for this job you can write it like this:
cause number is not iterable data type

```
for num in range(3 ** 2000):
  print(num)
```